# RSpec controller ajax request test

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am testing my controller but requests are coming via ajax. I do not know how I can approach this problem. I am trying way like HTTP requests but I user XHR before the HTTP request. However when I run the test, I see this problem,

```
1) RwsController Update widget score takes widget rate information
     Failure/Error: mock_widget.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
       (Mock "Widget_1003").update_attributes({"these"=>"params"})
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/controllers/rws_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have a controller, all ajax request are recording DB in here,

```
class RwsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'widget'
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:edit, :update, :show, :getUserInfo]
  respond_to :js, :json, :html

  #cookie check and show exact view
  def show
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
    if cookies["last_widget_id"] == @widget.uuid
      render :action => "generate"
    end
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
  end

  def edit
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
  end

  #after rating the rates and other details record on DB
  def update
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
    #logger.info("score-in:  " + params[:score])
    @widget.score = params[:score].to_i
    @widget.total_score = params[:total_score].to_i
    @widget.click_number = params[:click_number].to_i
    @widget.average = params[:average].to_i
    #set cookie
    cookies[:last_widget_id] = {:value => @widget.uuid, :expires => 1.year.from_now}
    @widget.save!
    render :text => 'ok'
    logger.info("score-out:  " + @widget.score.to_s)
    logger.info("cookie-id:  " +  cookies[:last_widget_id])
  end

  #iframe creates and calls .js.erb file
  def generate
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
    #@widget_id = @widget.id
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  #recording the visitor who visit the page
  def getUserInfo
    data = params[:mainURL]
    data1 = params[:mainBrowserAgent]
    data2 = params[:mainReferer]
    data3 = params[:mainDisplayInfo]
    data4 = params[:currentWidgetId]
    @widgetTraffic = WidgetTraffic.new(params[:widget_traffic])
    @widgetTraffic.widget_id = @widget_id
    @widgetTraffic.main_url = data
    @widgetTraffic.main_browser = data1
    @widgetTraffic.main_referer = data2
    @widgetTraffic.main_display = data3
    @widgetTraffic.widget_id = data4


    @widgetTraffic.save!
    render :text => 'ok'
  end
end
```

All scenario is that A user visit the side and click the link which has some information like score and others and ajax sends the data to controller to save it as you see in controller.

But I can not solve it? How can I?

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update method updates the @widget object without using update_attributes:

```
 def update
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
    #logger.info("score-in:  " + params[:score])
    @widget.score = params[:score].to_i
    @widget.total_score = params[:total_score].to_i
    @widget.click_number = params[:click_number].to_i
    @widget.average = params[:average].to_i
    #set cookie
    cookies[:last_widget_id] = {:value => @widget.uuid, :expires => 1.year.from_now}
    @widget.save!
```

However, your test for update expects that you will call
    @widget.update_attributes(params)

```
1) RwsController Update widget score takes widget rate information
     Failure/Error: mock_widget.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
       (Mock "Widget_1003").update_attributes({"these"=>"params"})
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

I think most probably, the original update method did call update_attributes and then that code was modified. That is why the test is failing now.

Comment: I fixed my spec controller like,
describe "Update widget score" do
    it "takes widget rate information" do
      WidgetTraffic.stub(:new).with({'these' => 'params'}) { mock_widget_traffic(:save => true) }
      xhr :put, :update, :widget_traffic => {'these' => 'params'}
      assigns(:widget_traffic) == @mock_widget_traffic
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

Comment: but I saw these error in this time,
1) RwsController Update widget score takes widget rate information
     Failure/Error: put :update, id: @widget, widget: Factory.attributes_for(:widget)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `score=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/rws_controller.rb:23:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/rws_controller_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: That means Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid]) is returning nil. You can use rails console to debug this problem by looking at the SQL generated and checking your table data.

Comment: Why is it nil? I do not get it. There are some data in my local DB.

Comment: Look at the SQL generated by this query. If you still think it should give you data, execute that sql query in the database client and see what results you get.